# Click trigger changes in other child of multiple parent parent component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have this kind of design :

```
ParentComponent [child-1[child-1-1 [child-1-1-1]]]
```

`child-1-1-1` have a list in which clicking on the cells should open another component `DetailComponent` of the same level as `ParentComponent`

Also important `DetailComponent` need for it's initialisation a string id passed from `child-1-1-1`

I can't use `@input` or `@viewchild`, it would add too much complexity in communication between component

How should I do that ?

Comment: `@input` and `@output` is there to communicate between components

Comment: yes but with only one level, like master/detail, but for me it's a really bad design. It'll lead to cascade calls if you see what I mean... And I have a lot of other cases of this kind. So it would rapidly become confusing. If you have a solution that let child-1-1-1 communication directly with ParentComponent feel free to show me

Comment: Consider using redux or something like this.

Comment: Use a service with a Subject (RxJS) or Redux (Ngrx for example).